# AMP Page - Fontawesome icons not showing on mobile

Tags: font-awesome, amp-html

I just made AMP pages for my website, and everything seems to be fine when I test the website through desktop browser (Chrome), both in normal view and phone-view.

However, I just attempted to access a webpage through Google (which is now showing the amp icon), but when I visit the page, the fontawesome icons aren't showing, which hurts the user interface.

I have this code in the  section.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="hidden" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Any ideas why the icons aren't showing up on mobile?

Comment: Just looked at the whitelisted FA URIs AMP allows. Which might be the problem here, they allow https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com, https://use.fontawesome.com. But this is https://pro.fontawesome.com.

Comment: And on the third note.. This is probably because this is set to only be loaded from a specific domain, and Google previews through another domain? So either you need to whitelist all Google domains in Fontawesome pro dashboard, or find somewhere else to load the latest pro icons

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging, I finally found the fix for this.

The resources are being loaded through cdn.ampproject.org, and you get a custom subdomain for your own domain, so lets say your domain is example.com, you need to whitelist **example-com.cdn.ampproject.org** in Font Awesome.